# Símbolo correcto para separar dos frases

Tags: ortografía

Me gustaría separar dos frases como las siguientes:

> Publicado el día 30 de Nov. del 2015 (separador) Aproximadamente 10 palabras escritas.

Pero me pregunto si existe algún símbolo además del punto o el guión, y que a la vez sea ortográficamente correcto. Gracias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creo que el punto (*punto y seguido*) es tu mejor opción. Es por definición el símbolo usado para separar dos frases.

No quieres un *punto y aparte*, porque no vas a empezar un nuevo párrafo. La *coma* es una breve pausa, que te podría valer, pero si quieres remarcar las frases como independientes usa el punto. Los dos puntos (:) es sólo una pausa mayor que llama la atención sobre le texto que precede (citas o enumeraciones). El punto y coma (;) separa dos frases relacionadas, por ejemplo

> Juan estudia ingeniería en la universidad politécnica; Ana derecho en la autónoma

No digo "Ana **estudia**", pero se entiende por el contexto de la frase previa, y en lenguaje escrito la unión de esas frases se hace mediante un punto y coma. El punto y coma une esas dos frases, independientes pero relacionadas en una sola, así que no hace los que buscas (separar las frases) si no lo contrario.

Por último, el guión se usa como separador de palabras, más que como separador de frases.

Así que mi sugerencia es **usar un punto y seguido**.

Comment: Fantástica respuesta y descripción de cada uno de los signos. En el ejemplo que das, también quedaría bien una coma tras "Ana" para dar énfasis a la diferencia entre los dos sujetos: "Juan estudia X; Ana, Y".